# Проверка ввода в поле с частичной подстановкой

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть задача - надо реализовать проверку ввода в поле улицы с подстановкой улицы и возможностью дописать дом /квартиру. Пример, клиент вводит название улицы, ему предлагаются варианты, после ввода улицы в этом же поле клиент может без проблем дописать дом и квартиру.Важный момент - после ввода улицы необходимо  проверить улицу на принадлежность к тому или иному району. Можно ли сделать это при помощи autocomplete или каким-либо еще решением ?

Comment: А данные с чем сравнивать?

Comment: Предполагаю использовать ФИАСовский справочник, данные по необходимому городу залью в mysql.